# Several variables contour integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis, several-complex-variables

Suppose I have an entire function of $n$ complex variables $f \colon \mathbb C^n \to \mathbb C$ and $f$ is rapidly decreasing (or enough conditions to make the following work). I want to show that $$\int_{\mathbb R^n} f(x) \, dx = \int_{\mathbb R^n} f(x+i\eta) \, dx$$
for any $\eta \in \mathbb R^n$. In the case $n=1$ I can just apply Cauchy's theorem integrating along a rectangle and show that the integral along the vertical lines vanishes. But what if $n>1$? I thought about applying Stokes' theorem, but does this work and what shape do I parametrize? Or is applying Cauchy's theorem to every variable seperately possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Stokes' on the strip $S=\mathbb{R}^n\times[0,1]$ viewed as a noncompact(*) submanifold-with-boundary of $\mathbb{C}^n$ via $(x,t)\mapsto x+it\eta$, with the $n$-form $\omega=f\,\mathrm{d}z^1\wedge\dots\wedge\mathrm{d}z^n$ on $\mathbb{C}^n$.  Note that $\partial f=0$ for degree reasons, and $\bar{\partial}f=0$ since $f$ is holomorphic, so $\mathrm{d}f=0$.

(*) Note that $f$ being holomorphic and rapidly decreasing on each translate of $\mathbb{R}^n$ implies $\omega$ is a $C^k$-limit and hence an $L^1_k$-limit of compactly supported forms on a neighbourhood of $S$, hence Stokes' can be applied.

If instead, you want to use Riemann integration and the compact version of Stokes', then consider the solid cylinder $D_R\times[0,1]$.  In the limit $R\to\infty$ the two parallel faces combined to give
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x+i\eta)\,\mathrm{d}x-\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
so it suffices to show the contribution from the curved face $S'=(\partial D_R)\times[0,1]$ vanish in the limit.  By the M-L estimate, its contribution is at most
$$
\operatorname{Area}(\partial D_R)\cdot\sup\{|f(x+it\eta)|:x+it\eta\in S'\}=cR^{n-1}\sup_{S'}|f|
$$
where $c$ is a constant (the area of the unit $(n-1)$-dimensional sphere, which is $\dfrac{2\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2)}$).  Now since $f$ is holomorphic, $|f|$ is pluriharmonic and hence harmonic, so [Harnack's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harnack%27s_inequality) allows you to bound $|f(x+it\eta)|$ by a constant multiple of $|f(x)|$ independent of $x\in D_R$, $t\in[0,1]$ for fixed $\eta\in\mathbb{R}^n$ (you can make this constant independent of $x,R$ by translation in $\mathbb{C}^n$ and treating each imaginary line segment separately).  Finally, $f$ is rapidly decreasing on $\mathbb{R}^n$ so $R^{n-1}\sup_{D_R}|f|$ can be made as small as you like for large enough $R$.

Comment: Thanks! Could you maybe elaborate on how the integration is carried out? I want to explicitly show that the integral along parallels to the imaginary axis vanishes...

Comment: There are no "parallels to imaginary axis" to consider here in this method, because $\omega$ is the $C^k$-limit of compactly supported forms.  If you want to use Riemann integration and the compact version of Stokes' then you have integral on the "cylindrical" surface $S'=(\partial D_R)\times[0,1]$ of $f$, which the M-L estimate says is at most $cR^{n-1}\sup_{S'}|f|$ and $|f|$ is rapidly decreasing on $S$ by e.g. Harnack's type bound with the ball of radius $2R$ to get something like $cR^{n-1}\sup_{S'}|f|\leq 4cR^{n-1}\sup_{D_R}|f|\leq c'/R$, and then take limit $R\to\infty$.

Comment: To get the compactly supported forms of small $C^k$-deviation from $\omega$, cut off with a bump function that has a large enough neck region so you can control all derivatives up to $k$-th order.  To show $C^k$-limit implies $L^1_k$-limit, use Harnack's inequality and the bump function bounds to control the contribution from outside $D_R$.

Comment: Alright, I see. I guess I am sticking with the compact version, since that one is more familiar to me. Anyway, thanks for your help :)

Comment: I've added a few words about the compact version, which isn't really much more than what I wrote in the comments.